# Is it possible to create an atomic transaction covering multiple nodes using Firebase Cloud Functions on Realtime database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So, the Firebase Realtime database only supports transactions over a single node. Is there a way to use a Firebase cloud function to create such functionality?

Is there a way to create a Function that works like a "synchronized method" in java, such that even if this function gets called from multiple users at once, the calls will be queued and executed sequentially?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  Cloud Functions can't deal with the database differently than any other database client.  Cloud Functions can (and often will) run in parallel on different server instances.  [Watch this video for more information](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCpKxpIMg6o&t=1s).

Comment: so, only solution is to migrate to Firestore I think?

Comment: Or organize your data such that the transaction you need can actually be done.